# "What I want least is..." or " what I want the least is..."?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Please tell me if I need to use the definite article in the following sentence.

> What I want (**the**) least is to work there.

I feel that I need to use *the* there. If I am right, please tell me why it should be there.

Comment: It's optional; the sentence works with or without it. The choice is yours.

Comment: Not sure, but hope this article can help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88362/the-usage-of-the-with-least

Answer (score 2):

*Least* is an **adverb** in your sentence. It means we can use *the*, or we can omit it. If *least* were the superlative adjective, we would have to use *the*. Compare:

> He is **the best** person I know. ("best" is the superlative form of "good").
>
> I like this dress **best/the best**. ("best" is an adverb)
>
> At **the least** sign of trouble, he gets scared and quits. ("least" is the superlative form of "little")
>
> The man who actually won the car is the one who wanted it **the least/least**. ("least" is an adverb)